# How do I force a culture in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, globalization

I want to be able to set the culture during runtime.  For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Culture = "fr-FR";
    Page.UICulture = "fr";
}
```

But that's not having any effect.  I'm using resource files for translation.  If I change the language of my browser it works fine, but I want the user to also be able to choose the language as well.  So in this case the user wants French as the language.

Any ideas?  I'm lost.

Comment: You want to force the culture but let the user choose?  Seems like conflicting requirements.

Comment: Try to set `Thread.Current.Culture` in Global.asax.

Comment: I want to force the culture that the user has selected. Which is why is put "example" in my code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're creating a site where you are allowing the user to change language for example, then you need to perform this in the `Global.asax` file in the `Application_BeginRequest` method.

Each request will then have the culture set.

You simply set the following 2 lines:

```
    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

The first line will set the number/date/etc formatting.

The second line specifies which resource localization to load - which will contain your translated content.

Comment: Perfect.  I was having another issue.  The culture was set in the page directive to auto, and that was overriding the change in global.asax.  All better now.  Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :) if it cured the problem please do mark it as answered - it helps future users too :)

Comment: I'm trying, but stackoverflow is making me wait.  You're too damn fast I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Refer this article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to set it for whole application, you can set it in your `Global.asax` as

  Thread.Current.Culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");